# Far future story where space travel and alien conquering has split the human race into distinct breeds

Tags: story-identification, books

The story takes place very far in the future. Space travel and alien conquering has split the human race into distinct breeds. There are humans who live on some moon in the solar system (possibly Jupiter) who are extremely intelligent, wild humans that live on earth, bull humans that were bred by the alien species for meat, less intelligent humans that were breed to look after the bulls, and space traveling humans that I think were pirates.

The story starts with a female protagonist who lives on the moon colony. The colony is run by an AI, which forms the foundation of the government of humankind. It selects some individuals (including the protagonist) out of all of human kind to breed and produce powerful offspring. These offspring then breed to produce an even more powerful being. The end goal is to create the ultimate human in order to eliminate the alien race that enslaved them. This takes a long time since each new being needs to age to maturity.

The program succeeds and they send the ultimate human (who is male) to destroy the aliens. He takes over one of the alien craft, and travels to a planet that has the alien species on it, but they are not the bloodthirsty ones that humankind were dealing with. He finds the home planet of the aliens and finds out that they have all been controlled by another parasitic species of aliens, which he destroys.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Your question has been closed as a duplicate, but please don't feel that that is a commentary on your question. We just link story-identification questions about the same work via the Duplicate system to improve the ability to find works in the future. You will still get points for upvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[I, Weapon](https://schlock-value.com/2014/05/11/i-weapon/)* by Charles Runyon

> Ancestry: Programmed
>
> Destiny: Unpredictable
>
> To create the man named Raki, Earth had broken its most rigid taboos against interbreeding.
>
> His grandparents were a four-foot tall female genius; a rapacious, blue-skinned space brigand; an enormous superstud gladiator with long, silky fur; and a blind telepathic huntress.
>
> His parents were the most gifted creatures ever to walk the earth—until Raki was born to surpass even them.
>
> But the supreme computer that had calculated the mating necessary to produce Raki refused to predict his chances in his confrontation with the alien Vim in the very heart of their eternally expanding empire…
>
> …for not even the Vim themselves knew the secret of their power and of all the universe’s peril…

The "genius" is from the moon colony. She mates with the purple-skinned space pirate. And the "superstud gladiator" is a member of the human subspecies, the Ungul, that were bred by aliens for meat and overseen by Grithies, who were bred for long earlobes because the aliens liked the look of them. Indeed, Raki goes to the alien homeworld and learns they are not the enemy, but rather the worms infesting them are.